# denied error with token login (Spring security)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, spring-security

I'm developing an API in spring boot, and in this api I have an authentication controller that I make a request with database login and password and I receive an authentication token

```
package com.api.business_manager_api.Controllers;

import com.api.business_manager_api.Dtos.LoginDto;
import com.api.business_manager_api.Security.JwtAuthenticationResponse;
import com.api.business_manager_api.Security.JwtTokenProvider;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser (@RequestBody @Valid LoginDto loginDto) {

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        loginDto.getUsername(),
                        loginDto.getPassword()
                )
        );

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        String jwt = jwtTokenProvider.generateToken(authentication);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtAuthenticationResponse(jwt));

    }
}
```

I'm getting the token correctly as expected, but the problem is that I can't authenticate it. When I try to join a private route I get the error "denied"

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar:6.0.1]
    at com.api.business_manager_api.Security.FilterToken.doFilterInternal(FilterToken.java:72) ~[classes/:na]
```

here the securityConfig

```
package com.api.business_manager_api.Config;

import com.api.business_manager_api.Security.FilterToken;
import com.api.business_manager_api.Services.UserDetailsServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private FilterToken filter;

    @Autowired
    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        return http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        authorizeConfig -> {
                            authorizeConfig.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user").permitAll();
                            authorizeConfig.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/auth**").permitAll();
                            authorizeConfig.requestMatchers("/error").permitAll();
                            authorizeConfig.requestMatchers("/user/**").authenticated();
                            authorizeConfig.anyRequest().authenticated();
                        })
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(filter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }
}
```

filterToken

```
package com.api.business_manager_api.Security;

import com.api.business_manager_api.Models.UserModel;
import com.api.business_manager_api.Repositories.UserRepository;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.Authorization;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.medialive.model.ClaimDeviceRequest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Optional;

@Component
public class FilterToken extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final String HEADER_AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization";
    private final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer";

    @Value("${app.jwtSecret}")
    private String jwtSecret;
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader(HEADER_AUTHORIZATION);

        if (authorizationHeader == null || !authorizationHeader.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        String token = authorizationHeader.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, "");
        try {
            Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(jwtSecret.getBytes())
                    .parseClaimsJws(token)
                    .getBody();


            String username = claims.getSubject();
            Optional<UserModel> user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

            if (user.isPresent()) {
                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
           ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(e);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

tokenProvider

```
package com.api.business_manager_api.Security;

import com.api.business_manager_api.Models.UserModel;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Date;

@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider {

    @Value("${app.jwtSecret}")
    private String jwtSecret;

    @Value("${app.jwtExpirationInMs}")
    private int jwtExpirationInMs;

    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication) {
        org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User userPrincipal = (org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) authentication.getPrincipal();

        UserModel userModel = new UserModel();
        userModel.setUsername(userPrincipal.getUsername());

        Date now = new Date();
        Date expiryDate = new Date(now.getTime() + jwtExpirationInMs);

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(userPrincipal.getUsername())
                .setIssuedAt(now)
                .setExpiration(expiryDate)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
                .compact();
    }
}
```

Yes, I am correctly sending the token by "Authorization" in the header of my request.

userDetailsService

```
package com.api.business_manager_api.Services;

import com.api.business_manager_api.Models.UserModel;
import com.api.business_manager_api.Repositories.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional <UserModel> optionalUser = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if (optionalUser.isPresent()) {
            UserModel userModel = optionalUser.get();
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(userModel.getUsername(), userModel.getPassword(),
                    new ArrayList<>());
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username: " + username);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not how you implement the handling of JWTs in spring security. Please read the official spring documentation on how to implement the resource server specification.

Comment: Are you referring to the filterToken?

Comment: yes, please read the oauth2/resource server/jwt section in the official spring security documentation.

Comment: Yes, I did that and it didn't work. Also just to be on the safe side, I directly put the string "Bearer " instead of a variable. Unsuccessfully...

Comment: @JunqRal  Then your code  is not matching the stacktrace. That means you new code was not compiled or not executed. Close your IDE and open it again, run it again an show the new stacktrace.

Comment: Do you refer to the stack trace before sending the request and the error occurs?

Comment: I noticed that sending my issued token here https://jwt.io/ I get Invalid Signature. Is there a chance that the wrong token is being issued?